# Pipelight flash plugin installation doesnt work with 16.04

Tags: firefox, flash, pipelight

I have recently installed 16.04 as a replacement for a 14.04.
Reinstalling flash plugin with pipelight, I have followed [the french ubuntu page for installing pipelight](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/pipelight). Everything seems to work fine except when at the end I go on the about:addons page from mozilla, I do not see shockwave, Cisco H264 is the only addon installed...
I have redone the all procedure twice, same issue.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

With Mozilla/firefox closed, run the following command:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
```

Open Mozilla and check `about:plugins`: it should now be listed.

You will probably have to do this every time the plugins are updated.